# Baby doing flips and flopping around constantly while breastfeeding, is he ready to be weaned?

Tags: infant, breastfeeding, weaning

My son is 9 months old and just won't be still while feeding. It's to the point where I can barely get him to stay latched, he keeps turning his head to look at other things, and I can't tell if he's had enough milk or not. I wanted to wait until one year to stop breastfeeding but I don't know how much longer I can continue like this.

Comment: Does he look around if you sit in a dark, quiet room too? My second was very easily distracted, so I had to sit somewhere quiet and dark to nurse him, then he ate lots. You may want to add your quest if he drinks water/milk from a cup/sippy, and if he gets lots of solid food.

Comment: Our daughter started being super distracted at 4 months. She is distracted more on the bottle then breast, but easily distracted on both. Its just your childs personality. You can help by minimizing other noises or introduce white noise, and dim the lights, or do it in the dark, or with a nursing cover.

Comment: Is he just turning his head, or also kicking his legs and such? My son had this drive to move and kick about when feeding since birth, more so when tired. He would continue drinking. The same for bottle feeds btw. He is almost 2 and he still likes to squirm and kick stuff when drinking.

Comment: My son ,7 months, also does turns ,flips and kicking while breastfeeding. He gets easily distracted . I have to take him to another room for feeding . He doesn't take feeder for milk.

Comment: My 8 month old like to try and do headstands while nursing.
I started just nursing while i lay on my back ans she lies her belly on mine. She actually stays still this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's going to eat enough, barring substantial physiological problems that it doesn't sound like apply here.  This was true at one month old, is true now, and will be true at 3 or 4.  Kids don't starve themselves, whatever their difficulties with appearing to eat a normal meal are.  As long as you're not replacing those calories with candy or potato chips, so all of his food options are nutritive ones, don't worry about the nutrition side of things.  Kids (like adults) have physical cues that tell them when they should be eating more or less, that make sure they get a sufficient minimum quantity of food.

As such, if you want to wean him, go ahead; if you don't want to, don't.  A lot of it depends on your preference, and whether you can handle him being so squirmy.  Health-wise, it is probably better for him to continue nursing for a portion of his calories until at least one (and even 1.5-2), due to the other benefits of breastfeeding, but it's not a dramatic difference; so if the squirming is getting to the point that it's stressing you out quite a lot, let it go.

This is a pretty normal stage right around 9 months give or take a few months, because babies start being able to move more (crawl, walk, etc.) around then, and their mental development also hits a higher gear around 9-12 months - so they're more interested in what is around them.  As was alluded to in comments, a less stimulating environment may be necessary to help keep this under control; but to some extent you may just have a happy, active baby who likes to move and see what's going on around him.

Other things you can do include talking to him to keep his attention - singing, telling him stories, etc.; stopping nursing when he reaches a certain point of squirminess, hoping to make it clear to him that squirming leads to stopping nursing; putting a blanket on him to keep him warm; and adjusting your nursing times.  By 9-10 months, my wife was primarily nursing in the early morning (upon waking up) and right before bed, both times when our babies were sleepy and less likely to squirm about, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Weaning is a personal choice for you and him. There is no magical date, but if you feel like he's ready and you're ready, then congratulations: you've done a great job.

If you're concerned about how much he's getting, you could give him known quantities of expressed milk in a cup or bottle-- but since you've been feeding him for so long, you can probably feel how much he's gotten. He may be looking around because he needs more interaction and sensory stimulation as he's growing up. You may find that talking to him or singing to him makes it more fun for him. Sounds like it may be time for a slow wean.